# Can we format SD card present in dslr from desktop connected over usb cable

Tags: ubuntu, camera, libgphoto2

I have to format the SD card present in dslr (Nikon d3400) from desktop (preferably ubuntu) connected over usb cable.

I am using ubuntu desktop with libgphoto2 camera library to control my dslr. I can capture image, record video, copy images from camera to computer, delete images etc.. I have also checked nikon sdk but couldn't find relevant help.

I want to know first whether formatting SD card and controlling power on/power off is possible or not. If yes, how can we achieve so.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and SuperUser cover more general questions that include hardware.

Comment: @tk421 thanks i will ask on recommended forums.